# Averaging cells in SSRS report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have now spent 3 hours trying every possible solution I've found, and until now failed miserably.

I need to average the contents of up to 4 cells on rows that multiply, depending on how many subjects a student takes. [pic of the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2ugC.jpg)

Each of the four cells contains an expression which finds the value for the different exam paper, this works fine.

=MAX(IIF(LCase(Fields!txtResultName.Value) = "% paper 1/writing(mfl)", Fields!txtResult.Value, Nothing))

Every attempt I've tried gives error messages, either when uploading or running. The only success I've had is in totalling the numbers together, which is pretty useless.

Comment: Reading your max statement, I'm not sure that the fields your creating are actually numeric values.  You can use Max on a text field, but you can't average a text field.  Also, your iif option is nothing, not 0.   Sample data would be most helpful

Comment: Thanks Adam, you're right about the data produced being text, I tried casting using Int() and that worked when I merely added the fields but when I used Avg it was rejected as only allowed aggregates in header or footer. What kind of sample data would help? Massive thanks for replying!

Comment: provide a table structure and a grid with sample values.  But checking the documentation,  I believe that average works over a column of data (or perhaps a row if you are using a tablix).  I'm not sure it's going to work for you format

Comment: Thanks Adam. I am using a tablix but will only need to average cells 3-6, ignoring 1-2 and result goes in cell 7. The tablix produces different subjects in the first cell, so the averages are per subject based on a different set of % that the =MAX statement pulls from the MIS. There is a picture of how it looks in the original post.

Comment: I would supply a sample of data as it comes out of your dataset and then expected results based on that sample. This should not be too difficult (famous last words!)